# jquery: how to show list in autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am playing with the autocomplete feature (code: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). One thing I would like to enhance is when the user puts the cursor in the box, a drop down list will show so that the user can also scroll down and select from the list. How to achieve that? Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The autocomplete plugin already does that ([demo](https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/maxheight.html)) (try typing "a")

Edit : I also found a link to [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LesignButure/EVsye/), second link by typing "jquery scrollable autocomplete" in google ;) It changes the prototype of the base jquery script though.

```
$.extend($.ui.autocomplete.prototype, ....
```

Comment: You didn't read my question carefully. What I mean is before you type anything, just put the cursor in the box will show the list.

Comment: There are comments in the JSFiddle that explain well. However I couldn't post the JSFiddle link without writing some code as well (StackOverflow policy), so I had to include a dummy line of code in my answer.